# Ibid. instead of authoryear on odd numbered pages

Tags: bibtex, biber, double-sided, ibidem

I am puzzled about a strange thing apparently happening in scrbook. I am using authoryear-ibid style and nothing special (I don't think). The result I would like to get is that "ibid." is not used when we go to a new page. This is, as far as I am aware the standard for authoryear-ibid style. What's buggering me is this: On odd pages, but *odd pages only*, it produces "Ibid." instead of the "authoryear".

Example:
I quote "Steiner 1994, p. 67" on page 1.

Quoting the same again on page 2, gives correctly:
"Steiner 1994, p. 67"

Quoting the same again on page 3, gives incorrectly:
"ibid., p. 67"

It continues in this fashion for the entire document. "Ibid." is always given on odd numbered pages but it works fine on even numbered ones.

Does pagetracker somehow count doublepages as a singlepage? And is there an easy way to fix this?

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,
            autocite=footnote,
            backend=biber,        
           ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{
@article{sigfridsson,
  author       = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title        = {Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
                  electrostatic potential and moments},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Computational Chemistry},
  date         = 1998,
  volume       = 19,
  number       = 4,
  pages        = {377-395}
}
}


\begin{document}


Lorem\autocite[380]{sigfridsson}
\clearpage
Ipsum\autocite[381]{sigfridsson}
\clearpage
Lorem\autocite[380]{sigfridsson}
\clearpage
Ipsum\autocite[380]{sigfridsson}
\clearpage
Lorem\autocite[380]{sigfridsson}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry everybody,

I just helped myself. But in case anyone else is having the same problem:

The issue is fixed by setting pagetracker=page.

Apparently, pagetracker=true is like pagetracker=spread when in twoside mode.